# "Server doesn't listen" in pgAdmin III with postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

First of all : I'm a novice in what touches to databases.

I'm using postgreSQL with pgAdmin III, and it worked perfectly fine until some days ago : Some days ago, when I was not working on it, I saw in the "background process" of Windows that several identical postgreSQL programs (?) were running, and I decided to stop them, because I was not using them at the time. Mistake : Now, when I try to connect to the server (on localhost), I receive the error message :

> "Server doesn't listen"
>
> The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 
>    could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I already took a look on similar topics on stackoverflow, looked the listen_address file, the postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf files, but everything seems to be "normal" (according to what I read in these topics).

I posted this because... well, I didn't find any other person that did what I did (stopping the background process, and then not being able to reconnect).

Comment: You *did* restart the Postgres service, did you? (btw: it's normal to have more than one postgres process even when the DB is idle, see e.g.: here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-ps.html).

Comment: Well... Since I didn't remember what I did when I connected to the server the first time, after searching a bit how to restart it (in vain), I supposed that pgAdmin automatically launched it when I try to connect... Apparently that's not the case ?

Comment: No, pgAdmin does not start any server, it only _connects_ to them. In a default installation, Postgres is registered as a Windows service. So you need to start the service from the Windows control panel.

Comment: I tried to start the postgres service (in commande line, since I couldn't find it in the control panel - no error occured, so apparently, it worked), but I can't see it in the background (or foreground) process, and I still can't connect.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736564%28v=ws.10%29.aspx or http://www.wikihow.com/Start-Services-in-Windows So how did you "start" Postgres from the command line?

Comment: Went into postgressql/9.4/bin, and wrote :
postgres -D "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/data"
as advised on top of this page :
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/server-start.html

Comment: I tried in the Services, it told me that "the postgresql service started but stopped, which can happen if it is not used by other services or programs"

Comment: If you are using a windows server, you probably aren't hosting anything critical on it. Perhaps restart the server altogether and save yourself the hassle? the services should restart properly at startup.

Comment: Yep, nothing important on the server (even if I lost it, it wouldn't be a problem). I just can't manage to start the postgreSQL service again : each time I try, it is immediatly shut down, whether it be from line command or from the "Services" pages.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled postgresql, and it works now. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 17):

Use Services (Start → Run → services.msc) and look for the postgresql-[version] service. Is it running?

- If not, try to start it.

  - If that works, you can make it startup automatically by changing the Startup Type with Windows to `Automatic`; or perhaps `Automatic, delayed start` if you don't want it to slow down startup too much.
- If you can't start it, you may have just installed pgAdmin and not installed PostgreSQL itself.
- If it won't start open the Event Viewer (Start → Run → Eventvwr) and look for error messages relating to the PostgreSQL service.

Answer (score 3):

Edit `\data\postgresql.conf` find and edit this line `listen_addresses` to

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

and uncomment

```
port = 5432
```

Comment: It works well if I set it to '*' but it seems not being very safe. No ? 

What if I only want to set only private range of addresses ? 

I tried to set the listen_addresses to '192.168.0.0/24' but it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: @MikeVerrier does it work if you put something like this? listen_addresses = '192.168.1.100,192.168.1.101,192.168.1.110'

Comment: Yes, it works fine that way ... That's a possible solution that implies that I change all the accessing machines to fixed IP.

Is there anyway to keep them dhcp and still keep it working ?

Comment: The only way I see is to list all the possible ip addresses in the DHCP range you are using.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, **PostgreSQL does not listen on all available IP addresses** on the server machine initially. In order to access the server over the network, you need to enable listening on the address first.

For PostgreSQL servers starting with **version 8.0**, this is controlled using the "listen_addresses" parameter in the **postgresql.conf file**. Here, you can *enter a list of IP addresses the server should listen on, or simply use '*'* to listen on all available IP addresses. For **earlier servers** (Version 7.3 or 7.4), you'll need to set the **"tcpip_socket"** parameter to **'true'**.

You can use the postgresql.conf editor that is built into pgAdmin III to edit the postgresql.conf configuration file. After changing this file, you **need to restart the server process** to make the setting effective.

> If you double-checked your configuration but still get this error
>   message, it's still unlikely that you encounter a fatal PostgreSQL
>   misbehaviour. You probably have some low level network connectivity
>   problems (e.g. firewall configuration). Please check this thoroughly
>   before reporting a bug to the PostgreSQL community.

*Credits: PostgreSQL - Guru Hint.*

Answer (score 1):

If on Windows, it could be a Firewall issue. Try adding rules (TCP as protocol should work) for postgres using post 5432 (or whatever post you might use).

Answer (score 0):

Just go to task manager -> services -> postgresql-x64-9.4 - PostgreSQL Server 9.4(right click) -> start service
From there just refresh postgresql and connect, and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the given methods. The postgresql service was running fine. Finally, logged in as administrator in Windows. It worked. Guess, postgresql doesn't allow itself to be run in a non-admin user.